# Can every rational function be represented in barycentric form?

Tags: rational-functions

This [article about polynomial interpolation](http://www.alglib.net/interpolation/polynomial.php) claims that (it is known that) every rational function may be represented in barycentric form:
$$r(x)=\frac{\sum_{j=0}^N\frac{w_j}{x-x_j}y_j}{\sum_{j=0}^N\frac{w_j}{x-x_j}}$$
What about the rational function $r(x,y)=\frac{xy}{x^2+y^2}$? But even if I accept that we are talking only about univariate functions, I would still like to know a bit more about the cited statement:

1. Is this statement strictly true for $\mathbb R$, i.e. for any rational function $r(x)=\frac{p(x)}{q(x)}$ with $p,q\in\mathbb R[x]$ (polynomials with real coefficients) there are $w_j, x_j, y_j \in\mathbb R$ representing $r(x)$?
2. Is this statement strictly true for $\mathbb C$, i.e. for any rational function $r(x)=\frac{p(x)}{q(x)}$ with $p,q\in\mathbb C[x]$ (polynomials with complex coefficients) there are $w_j, x_j, y_j \in\mathbb C$ representing $r(x)$?
3. For $r(x)=\frac{p(x)}{q(x)}$ and $N=\operatorname{deg}p+\operatorname{deg}q$, is the set of $x_j\in\mathbb C$ for which appropriate $w_j,y_j\in\mathbb C$ exist open and dense in $\mathbb C^{N+1}$?
4. Where can I learn more about this topic, since when is this known, ... ?

Comment: In [*Barycentric Lagrange Interpolation*. Jean-Paul Berrut, Lloyd N. Trefethen.](https://people.maths.ox.ac.uk/trefethen/barycentric.pdf), the earliest references seem to be from 1997 of Jean-Paul Berrut. This is a case of an author citing another paper of himself as reference, so "it is known" might only refer to a very small set of people...

Comment: It's not clear, in your displayed equation, what $y_j$ denotes.

Comment: @JohnHughes You mean because $y_j$ is not just a coefficient, but also identical to $r(x_j)$? Maybe you have a good point, and it could be related to my troubles understanding the cited statement.

Comment: Actually, I assumed that $y_i$ denoted a variable. I think Trefethen and Berrut use $f_i$ for this, indicating that it's the value that you're trying to interpolate with some function $f$. Now that I think about it, $y_i$ is a perfectly good name too. :) I think if you read the first few pages of the paper cited by Thomas Klimpel, you'll find that the answer to item 1 is "yes". I suspect that "2" is also "yes", and that the proof's identical. Finally, the last page of the cited paper contains a bunch of historical remarks that should address item 4.

Answer (score 0):

I found a derivation in one of the papers from 1997 of Jean-Paul Berrut cited in [*Barycentric Lagrange Interpolation*. Jean-Paul Berrut, Lloyd N. Trefethen](https://people.maths.ox.ac.uk/trefethen/barycentric.pdf). The claim is that any rational function $r(x)=\frac{p(x)}{q(x)}$ with $\max(\operatorname{deg}p,\operatorname{deg}q)\leq n$ for $n+1$ distinct interpolation points $x_j$ with $q(x_j)\neq 0$ can be written in barycentric form
$$r(x)=\frac{\sum_{j=0}^n\frac{u_j}{x-x_j}r_j}{\sum_{j=0}^n\frac{u_j}{x-x_j}}$$
for $r_j:=r(x_j)$ and suitable weights $u_j$. The derivation is actually quite simple:

Let $l(x)=(x-x_0)(x-x_1)\dots(x-x_n)$ and $w_j=\left.\frac{x-x_j}{l(x)}\right|_{x=x_j}$. The barycentric Lagrange formula represents the denominator as $q(x)=l(x)\sum_{j=0}^n\frac{w_j}{x-x_j}q_j$. For $\tilde{p}(x):=l(x)\sum_{j=0}^n\frac{w_j}{x-x_j}q_jr_j$ we have $$\frac{\tilde{p}(x)}{q(x)}=\frac{\sum_{j=0}^n\frac{w_j}{x-x_j}q_jr_j}{\sum_{j=0}^n\frac{w_j}{x-x_j}q_j}=\frac{\sum_{j=0}^n\frac{u_j}{x-x_j}r_j}{\sum_{j=0}^n\frac{u_j}{x-x_j}}$$
with $u_j:=w_jq_j$, and $\tilde{p}(x)=p(x)$ follows from $\operatorname{deg}p\leq n$ and $q_j=q(x_j)\neq 0$. We have $p(x_j)=q_jr_j$, because $q_j=q(x_j)\neq 0$. So $\tilde{p}(x)$ coincides with $p(x)$ at $n+1$ points, and both are polynomials of degree less than $n+1$, so they are identical.

---

The article [*Some New Aspects of Rational Interpolation*. Claus Schneider, Wilhelm Werner](http://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/1986-47-175/S0025-5718-1986-0842136-8/) from 1986 uses the barycentric form for rational interpolation and highlights its advantages, but doesn't seem to waste time or space to state or prove such a basic fact about the barycentric form. It might indeed have been stated and proved for the first time by Jean-Paul Berrut, maybe because people at that time grew tired of basic folklore results which practitioners knew but didn't publish, because the results were not new or non-trivial enough.

A good place to find more information about rational interpolation might be the reference section of this [article about rational interpolation](http://www.alglib.net/interpolation/rational.php), i.e. the articles

1. *Recent developments in barycentric rational interpolation*. Jean–Paul Berrut, Richard Baltensperger and Hans D. Mittelmann.
2. *Barycentric rational interpolation with no poles and high rates of approximation*. Michael S. Floater, Kai Hormann.